# DFP refresh ad afer X seconds in view

Tags: google-dfp

i'm looking to also do this but using the GPT APi ( i'm pretty new to this coding stuff, so no real clue what doing, so looking for help in effect)

I found this in the GPT ApI docs:

3. Impression viewable listener, slot specific logic.
   The listener will be called when the impression is considered viewable.
   This event also operates at service level, but, as above, you can filter
   to respond only to a certain ad slot by using this pattern

   googletag.pubads().addEventListener('impressionViewable', function(event) {
   if (event.slot == targetSlot) {
   //Slot specific logic.
   }
   });

and already have this, which is refreshing the ads after X seconds

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
  var mappingleaderslot = googletag.sizeMapping().
  addSize([1024, 769], [[970,250],[970,90],[728,90],[468,60],[320,50],[234,60]]).
  addSize([768, 500], [[728,90],[468,60],[320,50],[234,60]]).
  addSize([1, 1], [[320,50],[234,60]]).
  build();
  var mappingbigboxslot = googletag.sizeMapping().
  addSize([1024, 769], [[300,600],[300,250],[160,600],[120,600],[250,250]]).
  addSize([768, 500], [[300,250],[250,250]]).
  addSize([1, 1], [[300,250],[250,250]]).
  build();
  topSlot = googletag.defineSlot('/1001824/prebid_test2', [[970, 250],[970, 90],[728, 90],[468, 60],[320, 50],[234, 60]], 'topSlot').defineSizeMapping(mappingleaderslot).setTargeting("test", "refresh").addService(googletag.pubads());
  middlerightSlot = googletag.defineSlot('/1001824/prebid_test3', [[300, 600],[300, 250],[160, 600],[120, 600],[250, 250]], 'middlerightSlot').defineSizeMapping(mappingbigboxslot).setTargeting("test", "refresh").addService(googletag.pubads());
  bottomrightSlot = googletag.defineSlot('/1001824/prebid_test1', [[300, 600],[300, 250],[160, 600],[120, 600],[250, 250]], 'bottomrightSlot').defineSizeMapping(mappingbigboxslot).setTargeting("test", "refresh").addService(googletag.pubads());
  bottomleftSlot = googletag.defineSlot('/1001824/prebid_test4', [[300, 600],[300, 250],[160, 600],[120, 600],[250,250]], 'bottomleftSlot').defineSizeMapping(mappingbigboxslot).setTargeting("test", "refresh").addService(googletag.pubads());
googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true, true);
googletag.pubads().setCentering(true);
googletag.enableServices();
googletag.display("topSlot");
googletag.display("middlerightSlot");
googletag.display("bottomrightSlot");
googletag.display("bottomleftSlot");
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([topSlot]);}, 120000);
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([middlerightSlot]);}, 120000);
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([bottomrightSlot]);}, 120000);
setInterval(function(){googletag.pubads().refresh([bottomleftSlot]);}, 120000);
});

function refreshSlot(slot) {
    pbjs.que.push(function() {
        pbjs.requestBids({
            timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT,
            adUnitCodes: [slot.getSlotElementId()],
            bidsBackHandler: function() {
                pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync([slot.getSlotElementId()]);
                googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);
            }
        });
    });
}
function refreshtopSlot() {
    refreshSlot(topSlot);
}
function refreshmiddlerightSlot() {
    refreshSlot(middlerightSlot);
}
function refreshbottomrightSlot() {
    refreshSlot(bottomrightSlot);
}  
function refreshbottomleftSlot() {
    refreshSlot(bottomleftSlot);
}
```

but no clue how i can combine the two, so as the ad refreshes once its been "in view" for X seconds, any pointers/can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look a this Gist, it has a full [code example](https://gist.github.com/bwarner/296bf487c1e4a4931d2ad70e05423c36).

Here is the Javascript example

```
var size = [
  //[300, 600],
  //[300, 250],
  //[160, 600],
  //[120, 600],
  [250, 250]
];
var PREBID_TIMEOUT = 1000;

googletag.cmd.push(function () {
  (function (googletag, pbjs, config) {
    var sizeMappings = {};
    var slots = {};
    function refreshSlot(slot) {
      pbjs.que.push(function() {
        pbjs.requestBids({
          timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT,
          adUnitCodes: [slot.getSlotElementId()],
          bidsBackHandler: function() {
            pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync([slot.getSlotElementId()]);
            googletag.pubads().refresh([slot]);
          }
        });
      });
    }
    Object.keys(config.sizeMappings).forEach(function (key) {
      var sizeMappingBuilder = googletag.sizeMapping();
      config.sizeMappings[key].forEach(function (mapping) {
        sizeMappingBuilder.addSize(mapping[0], mapping[1]);
      });
      var sizeMapping = sizeMappingBuilder.build();
      sizeMappings[key] = sizeMapping;
      console.log('created sizemapping ', key, ' ', sizeMappings[key]);
    });

    //googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs(true, true);
    googletag.pubads().setCentering(true);
    googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();
    googletag.enableServices();
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('impressionViewable', function (event) {
      var elementId = event.slot.getSlotElementId();
      var slotConfig = slots[elementId];
      if (slotConfig) {
        var handle = setTimeout(function () {
          googletag.cmd.push(function () {
            refreshSlot(event.slot);
          });
        }, config.definitons[elementId].timeout);
        console.log('handle for time ', handle, ' elementId ', elementId, ' duration ', config.definitons[elementId].timeout);
      }
    });
    Object.keys(config.definitons).forEach(function (key) {
      var def = config.definitons[key];
      var slot = googletag.defineSlot(def.adUnitPath, def.size, key);
      slot.setTargeting('test', 'refresh');
      slot.defineSizeMapping(sizeMappings[def.sizeMapping]);
      slot.addService(googletag.pubads());
      googletag.display(key);
      slots[key] = { slot: slot };
    });
    googletag.pubads().refresh();
  })(window.googletag, window.pbjs, {
    definitons: {
      topSlot: {
        adUnitPath: '/1001824/prebid_test2',
        size: size,
        sizeMapping: 'mappingleaderslot',
        timeout: 5000,
      },
      middlerightSlot: {
        adUnitPath: '/1001824/prebid_test3',
        size: size,
        sizeMapping: 'mappingbigboxslot',
        timeout: 3000,
      },
      bottomrightSlot: {
        adUnitPath: '/1001824/prebid_test1',
        size: size,
        sizeMapping: 'mappingbigboxslot',
        timeout: 3000,
      },
      bottomleftSlot: {
        adUnitPath: '/1001824/prebid_test4',
        size: size,
        sizeMapping: 'mappingbigboxslot',
        timeout: 3000,
      },
    },
    sizeMappings: {
      mappingleaderslot: [
        [
          [1024, 769],
          [
            [970, 250],
            [970, 90],
            [728, 90],
            [468, 60],
            [320, 50],
            [234, 60]
          ]
        ],
        [
          [768, 500],
          [
            [728, 90],
            [468, 60],
            [320, 50],
            [234, 60]
          ]
        ],
        [
          [1, 1],
          [
            [320, 50],
            [234, 60]
          ]
        ],
      ],
      mappingbigboxslot: [
        [
          [1024, 769],
          [
            [300, 600],
            [300, 250],
            [160, 600],
            [120, 600],
            [250, 250]
          ]
        ],
        [
          [768, 500],
          [
            [300, 250],
            [250, 250]
          ]
        ],
        [
          [1, 1],
          [
            [300, 250],
            [250, 250]
          ]
        ],
      ]
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: thanks alot Bewarnd, seems to work perfect, i just need to add it into the rest I have. big thumbs up

Comment: actually, the size mapping doesnt seem to work, its not changing the sizes when replicating ipad, iphone etc?

Comment: ok, thanks, that works as in it now sets the different sizes, another problem arrises though, seems as now pushing the prebid que/ bids again,, if their a size bigger than the sizemapping they display 9sometimes get 970x250 etc, when should be 728x90 biggest size).  i.e "breaking the size mapping' , errrr, any clues?

Comment: Prebid has its own size mapping scheme see http://prebid.org/dev-docs/examples/size-mapping.html

Comment: ok, thanks, how do you get the "allSizes" into the rest of the script you wrote? ( not having it there, which I dont have a clue how to do, seems to block loads of bidders)
   googletag.defineSlot('/19968336/header-bid-tag-0', allSizes, 'div-1')

Comment: I think i got this working now for prebid size mapping, there now seems to be another problem of on the first page load, prebid never renders an ad even thought there are bids there.  is it something to do with initAdserver, conflicting wityh the google size mapping etc?     function initAdserver() {
      if (pbjs.adserverRequestSent) return;
      pbjs.adserverRequestSent = true;
      googletag.cmd.push(function() {
        pbjs.que.push(function() {
          pbjs.setTargetingForGPTAsync();
          googletag.pubads().refresh();
        });
      });
    }

Comment: its not setting the key values from the prebid bids on the first page load basically, anyone any idea how to fix that?

Comment: can this be tweaked to lazy load the bottom slot?

Comment: You want to use something like [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) to do lazy loading, it will tell you when an element scrolls into view. With that information you can call refresh just for that ad slot.

Comment: better to use that than the google gpt way you think?

Comment: Yes, the viewability is not great for lazy loading, for example it won't fire if you scroll past ads quickly before they meet the viewability criteria. See (Viewability 
 and Active View)[https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/4524488?hl=en&visit_id=1-636685023980247194-846924266&rd=1]

Comment: any chnace to have a look/ help me fix an issue with prbid not setting key values on first load, i've looked at it for weeks now and just getting nowhere

Comment: i put it there what i have 
https://gist.github.com/spormeon/de3ff11dab116644a4742b07c0187243

Comment: I'll take a look at it, in the next couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

think i found another issue, if a prebid ad renders first,  it doest then push the prebid que/ page bids to the "next" prebid bid, it refreshes the same bid, so there is no subsiquent "rev" to be had.  i tried adding this but dont seem to work

```
googletag.pubads().addEventListener('impressionViewable', function 
(event) {
          var elementId = event.slot.getSlotElementId();
          var slotConfig = slots[elementId];
          if (slotConfig) {
            var handle = setTimeout(function () {
              googletag.cmd.push(function () {
                  function refreshBid() {
                      pbjs.que.push(function() {
                          pbjs.requestBids({
                              timeout: PREBID_TIMEOUT,
                              bidsBackHandler: function() {
                                  googletag.pubads().refresh([slot1]);
```